# How to tell compiler to auto replace interface type with type?

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, razor

I try to use SOLID, and use dependency injection design to loose couple. I splits RazorUI assembly and DbContext assembly (2 Project). So i can test whatever inside ViewModel as standalone. I curious ILogger < IndexModel > works. How to instruct compiler to know this things. As we see ILogger is interface

```
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/microsoft.extensions.logging.ilogger?view=dotnet-plat-ext-7.0
```

.

```
public class IndexModel : PageModel
{
  private readonly IApplicationDbContext _context;
  private readonly ILogger _logger;
  public IndexModel(ILogger < IndexModel > logger, IApplicationDbContext context) 
  {
    _logger = logger;
    _context = context;
  }
}
```

Is like theres something i need to setup in Program.cs to instruct cast IApplicationDbContext to ApplicationDbContext.

Comment: Im not entirely sure what you are asking, but casting in c# would be done by doing (ApplicationDbContext)(object)variable if the interface cannot be directly cast to the type, or simply (ApplicationDbContext)variable if it can.

Answer (score 0):

You need to configure your dependency injection container.

The way in which this is done varies by version. From the documentation:

> ASP.NET Core's built in DI system supports constructor injection, so it resolves implementations of dependencies passed in as parameters to the constructor method of objects. Before it can do that, the implementations must be registered with the container. Typically, implementations (or "services") are registered in Program.cs from .NET 6 onwards, or the ConfigureServices method in the Startup class in earlier versions of .NET.

For .NET 6 and up (Program.cs):

```
builder.Services.AddTransient<IApplicationDbContext, ApplicationDbContext>();
```

You can read more about other versions as well as additional details such as lifetime of your service instances [here](https://www.learnrazorpages.com/advanced/dependency-injection).